# Image transparency darkened when saved using OpenCv

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I created a drawing application where I allow the user to draw and save the image to later reload to continue drawing. Essentially, I'm passing the drawing as a bitmap to the JNI layer to be saved and the same to load a previous drawing.

I'm using OpenCv to write and read to png file.

I'm noticing something weird in terms of the transparencies of the image.  It almost seems as the transparency is being calculated against a black color on OpenCv? Take a look a the images attached, the contain lines that have transparencies.

**Correct transparency by passing int array to native code, no color conversion needed:**
[image]

**Darkened transparency by passing Bitmap object to native code, color conversion needed:** 
[image]

What could potentially be happening?

**Saving image using native Bitmap get pixel methods:**

```
if ((error = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(pEnv, jbitmap, &info)) < 0) {
    LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed! error:%d",error);
}

if (0 == error)
{
    if ((error = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(pEnv, jbitmap, &pixels)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", error);
    }
}

if (0 == error)
{
    if (info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
    {
        LOGI("ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888");
    }
    else
    {
        LOGI("ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT %d",info.format);
    }

    Mat bgra(info.height, info.width, CV_8UC4, pixels);
    Mat image;

    //bgra.copyTo(image);

    // fix pixel order RGBA -> BGRA
    cvtColor(bgra, image, COLOR_RGBA2BGRA);

    vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    compression_params.push_back(3);

    // save image
    if (!imwrite(filePath, image, compression_params))
    {
        LOGE("saveImage() -> Error saving image!");
        error = -7;
    }

    // release locked pixels
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(pEnv, jbitmap);
}
```

**Saving image using native int pixel array methods:**

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_vblast_smasher_Smasher_saveImageRaw
    (JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject obj, jstring jFilePath, jintArray jbgra, jint options, jint compression)
{
    jint*  _bgra = pEnv->GetIntArrayElements(jbgra, 0);
    const char *filePath = pEnv->GetStringUTFChars(jFilePath, 0);

    if (NULL != filePath)
    {
        Mat image;
        Mat bgra(outputHeight, outputWidth, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)_bgra);

        bgra.copyTo(image);

        if (0 == options)
        {
            // replace existing cache value
            mpCache->insert(filePath, image);
        }

        vector<int> compression_params;
        compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
        compression_params.push_back(compression);

        // save image
        if (!imwrite(filePath, image))
        {
            LOGE("saveImage() -> Error saving image!");
        }
    }

    pEnv->ReleaseIntArrayElements(jbgra, _bgra, 0);
    pEnv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jFilePath, filePath);
}
```

**Update 05/25/12:**
After a little more research I'm finding out that this issue does not happen if I get the int array of pixels from the bitmap and pass that directly to the JNI as opposed to what I do currently which is pass the entire Bitmap to the JNI layer then get the pixels and use `cvtColor` to convert pixels properly.  Am I using the right pixel conversion?

Comment: What is the value of `compression` ?

Comment: The value I've tried was 0, 3 and 9. They all produce the same results.

Comment: What version is this, and where did you downloaded it from?

Comment: I downloaded from the official "site" v2.4.0.  Please see updated part of my question.  There is something wrong with the way I convert the colors or the colors are getting mixed up with the conversion.

Comment: Do you actually need to do the conversion? Are you sure?

Comment: If I don't do the conversion all the colors are mixed and the darkened transparency is still seen.

Comment: Humm.. if you display the image before doing the color conversion and before storing it to the disk, it looks ok?

Comment: I tried caching the Mat on the native code without doing color conversion. The colors looked good but the darkened transparency issue was still there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will post a bug...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways representing alpha in an RGBA pixel, premultiplied or not. With premultiplication, the R, G, and B values are multiplied by the percentage of alpha: color = (color * alpha) / 255. This simplifies a lot of blending calculations and is often used internally in imaging libraries. Before saving out to a format that doesn't use premultiplied alpha, such as PNG, the color values must be "unmultiplied": color = (255 * color) / alpha. If it is not, the colors will look too dark; the more transparent the color, the darker it will be. That looks like the effect you're seeing here.

Comment: Mmm that could very well be the issue. I tested writing a few known pixel values on java layer than read those pixels on the native side using the calculation to div by the alpha and read those pixel values correctly.  Now I need to figure out how to convert all pixels save and see if that was the issue.

Comment: How would you blend two multiplied alpha pixels?

Comment: @Jona, simplicity itself: for channels (R,G,B,A) for images `top` and `bottom`, use `blended.c = ((255 - top.A) * bottom.c + top.A * top.c) / 255`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm very new to the whole imaging side of things and this is very interesting stuff :)

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing called as transparent image in opencv. The foreground and the background images are mixed appropriately to give the illusion of transparency. Check [this](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/transparent-image-overlays-in-opencv/) to see how its done.

Comment: The issue is not overlaying images but saving them properly keeping the transparency correctly.  The saved image is missing something. Almost as if the alpha channel was  swapped at some point?